# How come I can create objects with [pscustomobject] but not [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]?

Tags: powershell, object, types, hashtable

How come I can create objects with the type accelerator [pscustomobject] but not its fullname, [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]?  Is there some magical constructor I'm not accessing?

```
$a = [pscustomobject]@{name='joe'}
$a.gettype().fullname
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]@{name='joe'}
InvalidArgument: Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject".
```

Or I can try [System.Management.Automation.PSObject], but I just get a hashtable:

```
[psobject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')::get.pscustomobject.fullname
System.Management.Automation.PSObject

[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]@{name='joe'}                                                     

Name                           Value
----                           -----
name                           joe
```

Inspired by this thread:  https://powershell.org/forums/topic/type-accelerator

Comment: my understanding is that the `[PSCustomObject]` thing is an _accelerator_, not a type. it's a shortcut for making objects of the _type_.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Is there a way to see the definition, like what script it runs?  That get property in the 2nd box returns all the type accelerators.

Comment: other than digging into the source code, i am not aware of any such thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some magical constructor I'm not accessing?

No, there's magic sauce in the compiler - whenever the PowerShell compiler sees a cast expression where the right-hand side is a dictionary and the type literal has the exact name `pscustomobject`, it'll treat the dictionary or hashtable (whether literal or not) as an ordered dictionary and convert it to a `PSObject`.

From [`VisitConvertExpression` in Compiler.cs](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/b7cb335f03fe2992d0cbd61699de9d9aafa1d7c1/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/Compiler.cs#L6053-L6061):

```
var typeName = convertExpressionAst.Type.TypeName;
var hashTableAst = convertExpressionAst.Child as HashtableAst;
Expression childExpr = null;
if (hashTableAst != null)
{
    var temp = NewTemp(typeof(OrderedDictionary), "orderedDictionary");
    if (typeName.FullName.Equals(LanguagePrimitives.OrderedAttribute, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return Expression.Block(
            typeof(OrderedDictionary),
            new[] { temp },
            BuildHashtable(hashTableAst.KeyValuePairs, temp, ordered: true));
    }

    if (typeName.FullName.Equals("PSCustomObject", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // pure laziness here - we should construct the PSObject directly.  Instead, we're relying on the conversion
        // to create the PSObject from an OrderedDictionary.
        childExpr = Expression.Block(
            typeof(OrderedDictionary),
            new[] { temp },
            BuildHashtable(hashTableAst.KeyValuePairs, temp, ordered: true));
    }
}
```

Notice how this is also how `[ordered]@{Key='Value'}` results in an `OrderedDictionary`

Comment: The reason I was able to find it within 10 minutes was that _I already knew_ - familiarize yourself with the code base, submit a couple of patches, and you'll be a black belt PowerShell code navigator in no time ;-)